# Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "fc-dom-171" Client: "fc-dom-2" when using FullCalendar in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, fullcalendar

## Context

I'm using `FullCalendar v5.11.0`, `NextJS v12.0.7`, `React v17.0.2` and `Typescript v4.3.5`.

I wanted to create a simple calendar, based on [FullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react), so I've created a `Calendar` component that is containing this code:

```typescript
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import Card from '../Card/Card';
import styles from './Calendar.module.scss';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

type CalendarProps = {
  className?: string;
};

const Calendar = ({ className }: CalendarProps) => {
  return (
    <Card
      className={
        styles.calendarWrapper +
        (className !== undefined ? ' ' + className : '')
      }
    >
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        locale='fr'
        firstDay={1}
        headerToolbar={{
          start: 'prev next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        }}
        businessHours={{
          // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
          daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Thursday

          startTime: '7:00', // a start time
          endTime: '23:00', // an end time
        }}
        nowIndicator={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        weekNumbers={true}
        weekNumberFormat={{ week: 'numeric' }}
        initialView='dayGridMonth'
        eventColor='var(--sw-color-accent-300)'
        eventTextColor='var(--sw-color-primary-900)'
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

## My problem

Where I'm checking the `console.log`, I can see that error:

```
Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "fc-dom-1" Client: "fc-dom-2"

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

I've done research and I found that we can use dynamic import with Next.js to disable SSR for a component, but after some tries I can't understand how dynamic imports are working.

Here is the code I started to try, without finding a way to make it works:

```typescript
const FullCalendarWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('@fullcalendar/react').then((mod: any) => mod.FullCalendar),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

And the error I get:

```
Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.
```

I'm new with Next.js and FullCalendar, so I'm probably misunderstanding something, especially about dynamic imports. Does someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong or how to use FullCalendar properly with Next.js?

Comment: That's not the right syntax for `next/dynamic` imports with named exports. See [How to use dynamic import with a named export in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735539/1870780).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried with that code : `const FullCalendarWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('@fullcalendar/react').then((mod: any) => mod.FullCalendar),
  { ssr: false }
);` but I get this error `Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.` (I updated my post so you can see the code with more readability)

Comment: I would suggest you dynamically import your custom `Calendar` component instead, wherever it's used.

Comment: I just tried it now, but I still have the same error: `Warning: Prop \`id\` did not match. Server: "fc-dom-2" Client: "fc-dom-6"`

Comment: Here is a codesandbox which reproduce the issue, sorry for late reply : https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-next-js-warning-prop-id-did-not-match-server-fc-dom-171-client-fc-dom-2-dj9nzj?file=/components/Calendar/Calendar.tsx

Comment: Dynamically importing `../components/Calendar/Calendar.tsx` in the index page works for me. As I said, you'll want to dynamically import your own custom `Calendar` component instead.

Comment: Can you please share a link to your solution (sandbox for example) or put the code here ? Because when I tried it doesn't worked, so maybe I was doing something wrong... I was using dynamic import on my Calendar component, but has an error too, so yeah if you can share your solution I would appreciate

Comment: Sure, here's the modified version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-next-js-31hu2p.

Comment: Oh my god I feel so stupid, I totally forgotten that I had another calendar made in another component, which is why I was still having the issue on the same page after dynamically importing my Calendar component, so I dynamically imported the other component that I made, and the issue is now solved! Thanks a lot for your help, feel free to publish an answer to the reply so I can set it as solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically import your custom `Calendar` component instead, wherever it's used. This ensures all `@fullcalendar` dependencies are dynamically imported on the client-side.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Calendar = dynamic(() => import('../components/Calendar/Calendar'), {
    ssr: false
});

export default function IndexPage() {
    return (
        <Calendar />
    );
}
```

You should also make sure you're not importing `@fullcalendar` anywhere else in your code, as that may still trigger the error.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-next-js-31hu2p