# Document is not defined - Mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mapbox

I am trying to put the latest version of `@mapbox/search-js-react` version 1.0.0-beta.12 into my nextjs application however when I do I get the following error.

> Server Error ReferenceError: document is not defined This error
> happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed
> in the terminal window.

Now the logs show the following

> Call Stack Object.
>
> file:///Users/USERNAME/Node_Projects/(APP)/node_modules/@mapbox/search-js-web/dist/index.js
> (1:1939)

Here is the code below.

```
import { getSession, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AddressAutofill } from '@mapbox/search-js-react';
import Dashboard from '../../../components/layout/dashboard';
import { Container, Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function Details({ signOOut }) {
  if (signOOut == true) {
    signOut();
  }

  //    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  //    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  return (
    <form>
      <AddressAutofill accessToken='pk.eyJw'>
        <input
          name='address'
          placeholder='Address'
          type='text'
          autoComplete='address-line1'
        />
      </AddressAutofill>
      <input
        name='apartment'
        placeholder='Apartment number'
        type='text'
        autoComplete='address-line2'
      />
      <input
        name='city'
        placeholder='City'
        type='text'
        autoComplete='address-level2'
      />
      <input
        name='state'
        placeholder='State'
        type='text'
        autoComplete='address-level1'
      />
      <input
        name='country'
        placeholder='Country'
        type='text'
        autoComplete='country'
      />
      <input
        name='postcode'
        placeholder='Postcode'
        type='text'
        autoComplete='postal-code'
      />
    </form>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const Gsession = await getSession(ctx);

  var signo = false;
  console.log('Checking Session are : ' + JSON.stringify(Gsession));
  if (Gsession) {
    if (Gsession.error == 555) {
      signo = true;
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      sessions: Gsession,
      signOOut: signo,
    },
  };
}

Details.auth = true;

Details.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <Dashboard>{page}</Dashboard>;
};
```

Comment: Call `signOut()` inside a `useEffect` so it only runs on the client-side.

Comment: @juliomalves that is not causing the issue - but thanks. The issue is caused by the plugin

Comment: Dynamically import the `AddressAutofill` component using [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-named-exports) with `ssr: false` to avoid server-side rendering issues. See [How to use dynamic import with a named export in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730573/how-to-use-dynamic-import-with-a-named-export-in-next-js).

Comment: @juliomalves that's the answer I needed thank you so very much - Please make that an answer and I'll approve it.